# In a 2D array in C why is the Base address of first element of 2D array and Base address of the very first row same?

Tags: arrays, pointers

suppose we have an `array A[m] [n]`.  I have found that `A=A[0]`.  If both of the terms contains address only then why not `*A` and `*A[0]` gives same results? 
 Assume that first element is `2` and it's Base address is `1000` then if both `A` and `A[0]` contains `1000` then dereferencing of both the terms should yield the same result that is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is not equal to `A[0]`, but `A=&A[0][0]`, i.e, `A` is a pointer to the first element of the matrix. `A[0]` is a pointer to `A[0][0]`.

So:

- `*A` gives the address of `A[0]`;
- `*(A[0])` gives 2;
- `*(*A)` gives 2;

For instance:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int A[5][5];

    A[0][0] = 2;

    std::cout<< *A << std::endl;
    std::cout<< *(*A) << std::endl;
    std::cout<< *(A[0]) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints:

```
0x7fffc5a6fc70
2
2
```